# In this example for the C++ Documentation Tutorial, why are the pointers declared twice?

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor

I'm working through the C++ Documentation Tutorial, and I'm having some trouble understanding this example of using pointers in a constructor:

```
// example on constructors and destructors
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class CRectangle {
    int *width, *height;
  public:
    CRectangle (int,int);
    ~CRectangle ();
    int area () {return (*width * *height);}
};

CRectangle::CRectangle (int a, int b) {
  width = new int;
  height = new int;
  *width = a;
  *height = b;
}

CRectangle::~CRectangle () {
  delete width;
  delete height;
}

int main () {
  CRectangle rect (3,4), rectb (5,6);
  cout << "rect area: " << rect.area() << endl;
  cout << "rectb area: " << rectb.area() << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

It seems that the pointer `*width` is declared twice. It is declared at the very beginning of the class: `int *width, *height;`, and it is also declared when the constructor is initialized `width = new int;`.

Why is it necessary to declare the pointer twice?

Comment: The int *width part doesn't actually create memory for the object the pointer points to, which is what the new int part does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) width = new int;

```
 It is not a declaration. You are allocating memory and assigning to width.
```

2) int *with   ->   is a declaration.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So just to clarify:
`width = new int` is only necessary when assigning dynamic memory, right?

Comment: yes, since width is a pointer variable, you need to allocate dynamically the memory.

Answer (score 4):

No, they are declared only once and in the constructor the values are being assigned.

Answer (score 1):

The variables are declared in the class body (i.e. telling the compiler that pointers to an int exist with the name *width* and *height*) with the statement `int *width, *height;` .

In the constructor, they are assigned a value, through the use of the new operator, it's not a declaration.

Comment: i am trying to understand how is this different from my answer, and why my answer has a downvote? Just asking...

Answer (score 1):

width = new int;
does not declare, it allocates memory from the heap.

Answer (score 0):

`int *width, *height;`  this just delcares placeholders

`width = new int;` actually allocates memory

Just for giggles, try commenting all your `new` in the constructor and see...your program **may** crash (http://ideone.com/bnxvKA) or you will get undefined behavior.

Comment: It might, also watch out for the nasal demons

Comment: Why not? it will write the value of `a` at the address in `width`. Since the value in `width` is some random garbage, you could see all kinds of strange things happening.

Comment: @Bill Whats wrong? You are suggesting to modify valid C++ code into code that results in undefined behaviour. Most compilers catch this and cause the program to crash, but sometimes only in debug builds (I'm 90% sure ideone uses debug build configuration, though I can't find the command they use to run GCC right now). But this is just a _nice_ feature of the compilers to catch mistakes, not something to rely on. Definitely not something to teach newbies. I'm not the downvoter btw.

Comment: @Fiktik I never said you are the downvoter. I wanted to reiterate the importance of allocating memory for a pointer, and thus suggested to comment the `new` out, you learn by your mistakes...with the change, the program will crash or you get undefined behavior. I have seen crashes most of the time, definitively something which should never be done or used.

Answer (score 0):

width and height are only declared once:

First, you tell width and height are `*int`

```
class CRectangle {
    int *width, *height; // declaration

(...)
```

Then, you give width and height a value (which is a pointer):

```
CRectangle::CRectangle (int a, int b) {
  width = new int; // assignment
```